# C++ How to loop this thing (beginner)

Tags: c++, loops

I'm figuring out how to loop my code and now it got me confused, any help would be much appreciated, im a beginner here so please don't scold me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    char ans;

    cout << "CONVERSION\n\n";
    cout << "Base 11 to Decimal\n";
        a:cout << "Base 11: ";
        getline(std::cin, str);
        const auto bad_loc = str.find_first_not_of("0123456789aA");
        if (bad_loc != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cerr << "Invalid Input\n";
            goto a;
        }
        unsigned long ul = std::stoul(str, nullptr, 11);
        cout << "Decimal: " << ul << "\n\n";
        cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> ans;
        if (ans == 'y')
        {
            goto a;
        }
        else if (ans == 'n')
        {
            cout <<"Name:\tXXXXXXXX\n";
            cout <<"Course:\tXXXXXXXX";
            cout <<"Section:\tXXXXXXXX\n";
            cout <<"Schedule:\tXXXXXXXX\n";
            cout <<"Professor:\tXXXXXXXX\n";
        }
        return 0;
}
```

the output should be like this

```
CONVERSION

Base 11 to Decimal
Base 11: B
Invalid Input!

Base 11: A
//blank
Do you want to continue (Y/N)? X
Invalid Answer! (Y/N)? Y
//blank
Base11:
```

My problems are
(1)The program stops after looping in "base11:" whenever i answer Y and (2)if I answer any letter from "Do you want..." the program will end. (3) How to fix this thing.

Comment: Put the code inside a `do {} while()` loop and check a sentinel if the input was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We beginners should help each other should not we?:)

The program can look something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "CONVERSION\n\n";
    std::cout << "Base 11 to Decimal\n";

    char ans;

    do
    {        
        std::string s;

        bool valid_input = false;
        while ( !valid_input )
        {
            std::cout << "Base 11: ";

            if ( !std::getline( std::cin, s ) ) break;

            if ( !( valid_input = s.find_first_not_of( "0123456789aA" ) == std::string::npos ) )
            {                
                std::cout << "Invalid Input\n\n";
            }
        }

        if ( !valid_input )
        {
            std::cout << "See you later!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        unsigned long value = std::stoul( s, nullptr, 11 );

        std::cout << "Decimal: " << value << "\n\n";

        std::cout << "Do you want to continue (Y/N)? ";
        std::cin >> ans;
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
    } while ( ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y' );

    std::cout <<"Name:\tXXXXXXXX\n";
    std::cout <<"Course:\tXXXXXXXX";
    std::cout <<"Section:\tXXXXXXXX\n";
    std::cout <<"Schedule:\tXXXXXXXX\n";
    std::cout <<"Professor:\tXXXXXXXX\n";

    return 0;
}
```

If the input looks like

```
B
A
Y
C
AA
N
```

then the output will be

```
CONVERSION

Base 11 to Decimal
Base 11: B
Invalid Input

Base 11: A
Decimal: 10

Do you want to continue (Y/N)? Y
Base 11: C
Invalid Input

Base 11: AA
Decimal: 120

Do you want to continue (Y/N)? N
Name:   XXXXXXXX
Course: XXXXXXXXSection:    XXXXXXXX
Schedule:   XXXXXXXX
Professor:  XXXXXXXX
```

Pay attention to statement

```
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

that skips the new line character entered after inputting `ans` using `operator >>`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helps a lot and the new code is on my brain now.

Comment: how about if i want to allow only letters "yY/Nn" on the "do you want..." question, am i going to add another code on the while thingy?

Comment: @JetMortolaJoseph You could use standard function std::strchr declared in header <cstring> the following way if ( !std::strchr( "YyNn", ans ) ) { /* some message */ } But In my opinion it is better just to repeat the loop if ans is not equal to 'n' or 'N'

Comment: @JetMortolaJoseph For example instead of the condition while ( ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y' ); you could write another condition while ( ans != 'n' && ans != 'N' );

Comment: I'm getting error with the 'stoul' and 'nullptr' in visual basic 6.0, and im afraid to put an alternate code because I don't know what's the replacement there :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105139/discussion-between-jet-mortola-joseph-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @JetMortolaJoseph Your question is about C++ is not it?

Comment: I moved to discussion chat, still c++

Comment: @JetMortolaJoseph I have a very slow internet and usually do not take part in chats.

Comment: got it on my new question. hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
bool run_attempt() {
  get some input
  if (bad input)
    return false;
  else {
    do something good with the input
    return true;
  }
}

void main() {
  bool success = false;
  while (!success) {
    success = run_attempt();
  }
}
```

Comment: Put your user interaction inside of run_attempt(). Let main() only handle the looping.